# JS: Replace a link with a link. And that link with a link

Tags: javascript

I am going to make a block of text, such that if you click on a word, it is replaced by a lexical substitute.

E.g. ''fearful-of-cats'' is a lexical substitute for ''ailurophobic'', because if you replace the latter with the former in any text, the meaning does not change.

However, I am having trouble with the function required to replace innerHTMLs of elements, even at this early stage.

Here is an example, and rough idea, of what the function looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><a href="#" id="Test_1" onclick=" replace(id,'Replacement 1') ">Test 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="Test_2" onclick=" replace(id,'Replacement 2') ">Test 2</a></p>

<script>
function replace(x, y) {
    document.getElementById(x).innerHTML = y;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

(That works when I save it to my Desktop as an .html file, but not on jsfiddle for some reason (otherwise I would link you to it.))

I would like you to show me the code revised, such that if I click on "Test 1", I get "Replacement 1". And **then** if I click on "Replacement 1", I get "ReReplacement 1".

The problem I currently have is to do with escape characters, I believe.

So, I would appreciate if your answer could shed light on where I may be going wrong with this in general. Thanks.

Comment: Change <a href="#" id="Test_1" onclick=" replace(id,'Replacement 1') "> tp <a href="#" id="Test_1" onclick=" replace("Test_1",'Replacement 1') ">

Comment: @jeff: That's no different. You can access element properties as variables when using inline handlers.

Comment: Might I ask why you want this to happen? And is the stuff added after the first click always going to be 'Re', or will that string vary?

Comment: The idea is: You have a piece of technical text, in whatever field.  In Wikipedia, there are links, which you may click on to find out more about a term, in great depth. I find myself, wanting often to be instantly reminded about the definition of a term only. So, in this case, the links on the technical text will be replaced with lexical substitutions, when you click on them. If you a read a sentence featuring the term A, and read the same sentence with its lexical substitute, the string L(A), then the meaning doesn't change and it remains grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

*****EIDT*****

Either this or the other works

```
<a href="#" id="Test_1" onclick=" replace('Test_1','Replacement 1') ">Test 1</a>
```

Comment: Weirdly enough, I thought the same thing. But I opened it using the snippet editor and sure enough, it works.

Comment: Should it be `this.id`?

Comment: I've always used `this.id`, but for some reason it works without the object reference, which I have to say confuses me a bit.

Comment: @Petty: Either way works in an inline handler. Think of it as the code running inside a `with (this) {...}`

Comment: @cookiemonster alright, figured as much. I'm not really seeing a problem with the code either.

Comment: Yes. That explains why the quoted code did not work in jsfiddle. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, though to be fair even with your base code I could never get the same error you speak of. I'm using the `data-replaced` attribute to determine whether or not the replace has been called already. I added a third parameter just in case the string will be changed later on. If not,whereever you see `prefix`, just change it with the string literal you want to use.

```html
<body>
<p><a href="#" id="Test_1" onclick=" replace(this.id,'Replacement 1','Re') ">Test 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#" id="Test_2" onclick=" replace(this.id,'Replacement 2','Re') ">Test 2</a></p>

<script>
function replace(x, y, prefix) {
  var el = document.getElementById(x);
  var replace_text = y;
  if(el.getAttribute('data-replaced')!=='true'){
     el.setAttribute('data-replaced',true);
    }else{
      replace_text = prefix+el.innerHTML;
    }
  
  el.innerHTML = replace_text;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What have I done! I shouldn't have said "ReReplacement 1", at all. It could have been "Test 1" "Replacement 1" "Banana 1" "Orange 3", the content of the replacement doesn't bother me. I accidentally conveyed an interest in the prefix "Re-". I will try to look at your code and see if I can get it.

Comment: Why, pray tell, would you want to do that?

Comment: The idea is: You have a piece of technical text, in whatever field. In Wikipedia, there are links, which you may click on to find out more about a term, in great depth. I often find myself wanting to be instantly reminded about the definition of a term only. So, the links on the technical text will be replaced with lexical substitutions, when you click on them. If you read a sentence featuring the term A, and read the same sentence with its lexical substitute, the string L(A), then the meaning doesn't change and it remains grammatical.

Comment: So, just to double check before I start hammering this out, If, via some auto parsed magic on your website, when someone wrote the phrase `I am agoraphobic`, there would be a link around 'agoraphobic', and when you clicked on it, it would replace the text with 'afraid of heights', making the sentence then `I am afraid of heights` ?

Comment: Yes, correct. Sorry for the late reply (work). I have 1000 lexical substitutions, and the test text necessary, so I just need this code!